# Android shell to execute a command as another user issue

Tags: android, shell

I am trying to execute the following command as a system user

```
su - system -c "ls -l /"
```

this is the output

```
shell@android:/data/xxxx/xxxx # su - system -c "ls -l /"
su - system -c "ls -l /"
SuperSU - Copyright (C) 2012 - Chainfire
```

does it mean in Android I can not use shell to execute a command as another user ? or a problem in `su` binary ?

how to I get the shell to execute as another user ? I tried creating a shell script also for this but still same output. Please advice.

Device is rooted already.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is SuperSU includes a `su` binary not compatible with standard GNU `su` one.

If you compile `su` for android with the NDK, and replace the binary it's going okay.

You can use this code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main (int ac, char **av, char **env) {
    int iret;

    if (ac == 1) { // Run /bin/bash as root
        iret = setuid(0);
        if (iret == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "This binary is u-s, use chmod u+s %s as root.\n", av[0]);
            exit(-1);
        }

        strcpy(av[0], "/bin/bash");
        iret = execve(av[0], av, env);
        if (iret == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't execute a shell.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    } else {
        struct passwd *pswd = getpwnam(av[1]); 
        //printf("%d\n", pswd->pw_uid);
        if (pswd == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "User %s does not exist.\n", av[1]);
            exit(-1);
        }
        iret = setuid(pswd->pw_uid);
        if (iret == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "This binary is u-s, use chmod u+s %s as root.\n", av[0]);
            exit(-1);
        }
        iret = execve(av[2], (char **)&av[2], env);
        if (iret == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compile it and change owner to root. then as root, run chmod u+s ./su. Finally as normal user run your command:

$ ./su system /bin/bash -c "ls -l /"